# Migrar de wix a otro hosting

Tags: migration, cms

Hola tengo un amigo que tiene  una pagina en wix y contrato otro servicio de hosting en nic. Cl pero no se como migrar el hosting de wix hacia alla,  alguna forma fácil y rápida de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? [Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Comment: Bueno solo leído wue según no se puede ya que esas paginas se hacen con una aplicación propia a la cual no se puede acceder al código generado es decir se copiaría el HTML pero se pierde el resto del diseño :/ si pregunto es porque no se ;(

Comment: Por como está formulada la pregunta se va a cerrar como basada en opiniones. Igualmente, no parece ser muy valida aqui la pregunta, quiza lo mejor sea contactar con Nic/wix para ver si tienen soluciones ante esas situaciones. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

CMS2CMS es un servicio de pago en el que se ocupan de hacer todo tipo de migraciones. El precio puede variar dependiendo del contenido que tengas pero en mis pruebas pude migrar la mayoría de los sitios Wix sencillos por unos míseros 9$ así que no es una opción para desestimar.

https://cms2cms.com/pricing/

[image: opciones para migrar en el sitio cms2cms]